# Can I have two vertical scrollview frames within a Box Layout? I'm struggling

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

This is my first post and I'm trying to follow the prompts, dunno if the post will follow what people normally do. I'm also pretty new to Python and Kivy (and programming full stop) so please excuse any incorrect use of nomenclature.

I'm trying to make a Display Card for recipes.
I watched and followed a few python and kivy tutorials and thought wow, this is so simple :)
The code here took me about 2 weeks so far lol

I thought it would simply be a case of adding the 2 scrollviews and setting them to vertical.
This hasn't worked.

I can't get the images to display using relative or full file paths and all of the populated text is at the top of the screen overlaying each other in an illegible mess. The image used was verified to work before i got tothis point.

I'm using the 2 recipes in the code block for now till i get it working, that and because I've still to find out how to do the database stuff

Python

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

recipes_data = [
    {
        'title': 'Spaghetti Carbonara',
        'description': 'Classic Italian dish with spaghetti, pancetta, and a creamy egg sauce',
        'image': 'C:/Users/Gael/PycharmProjects/Recipe_Card/images/juice.png',
        'ingredients': ['1 pound spaghetti', '6 ounces pancetta or bacon, diced', '4 large eggs',
                        '1 cup freshly grated Pecorino Romano cheese', 'Salt and freshly ground black pepper'],
        'instructions': '1. Cook the spaghetti in a large pot of boiling salted water until al dente.\n2. Meanwhile, cook the pancetta in a large skillet over medium heat until crisp.\n3. In a small bowl, whisk together the eggs and cheese.\n4. Drain the spaghetti and add it to the pancetta. Toss to combine.\n5. Remove the skillet from the heat and pour the egg mixture over the spaghetti, tossing quickly to coat. The heat from the spaghetti will cook the eggs and form a creamy sauce.\n6. Season with salt and pepper to taste and serve immediately.'
    },
    {
        'title': 'Beef and Broccoli Stir Fry',
        'description': 'Quick and easy stir fry with tender beef and fresh broccoli',
        'image': 'C:/Users/Gael/PycharmProjects/Recipe_Card/images/juice.png',
        'ingredients': ['1 pound flank steak, sliced thin', '2 tablespoons vegetable oil', '1/4 cup soy sauce',
                        '2 tablespoons brown sugar', '1 tablespoon cornstarch', '1/4 teaspoon ground ginger',
                        '4 cloves garlic, minced', '4 cups broccoli florets', '1/2 cup beef broth'],
        'instructions': '1. Heat the oil in a large skillet over high heat.\n2. Add the sliced beef and stir fry for 2-3 minutes, until browned on all sides.\n3. In a small bowl, whisk together the soy sauce, brown sugar, cornstarch, ginger, garlic, and beef broth.\n4. Add the broccoli to the skillet and stir fry for 2-3 minutes, until slightly tender.\n5. Pour the soy sauce mixture over the beef and broccoli and stir to combine.\n6. Cook for an additional 2-3 minutes, until the sauce has thickened.\n7. Serve over rice or noodles.'
    },
]


class RecipeCard(FloatLayout):
    title = StringProperty('')
    description = StringProperty('')
    image = StringProperty('')
    ingredients = ListProperty([])
    instructions = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = data['title']
        self.description = data['description']
        self.image = data['image']
        self.ingredients = data['ingredients']
        self.instructions = data['instructions']

        # Create the ingredients boxlayout
        self.ids.ingredients = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=dp(5), size_hint_y=None)
        self.ids.ingredients_grid.bind(minimum_height=self.ids.ingredients_grid.setter('height'))
        self.ids.ingredients.bind(minimum_height=self.ids.ingredients.setter('height'))
        self.ids.ingredients_label = Label(text='Ingredients:', font_size=18, bold=True,
                                           size_hint=(1, None), height=dp(30))
        self.ids.ingredients.add_widget(self.ids.ingredients_label)

        # Create the instructions boxlayout
        self.ids.instructions = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=dp(5), size_hint_y=None)
        self.ids.instructions_grid.bind(minimum_height=self.ids.instructions_grid.setter('height'))
        self.ids.instructions.bind(minimum_height=self.ids.instructions.setter('height'))
        self.ids.instructions_label = Label(text='Instructions:', font_size=18, bold=True,
                                             size_hint=(1, None), height=dp(30))
        self.ids.instructions.add_widget(self.ids.instructions_label)


class RecipesScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RecipesScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setup_widgets()

    def setup_widgets(self):
        # Create the layout
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=(0, dp(150), 0, 0))
        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        grid_layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        grid_layout.bind(minimum_height=grid_layout.setter('height'))
        scrollview.add_widget(grid_layout)
        box_layout.add_widget(scrollview)
        layout.add_widget(box_layout)
        self.add_widget(layout)

        # Have to build the recipe cards
        self.build_recipe_cards(grid_layout)

    def build_recipe_cards(self, layout):
        for recipe in recipes_data:
            # Create the card for the recipe
            card = RecipeCard(data=recipe)
            layout.add_widget(card)

            # Adding the ingredients
            ingredients = recipe['ingredients']
            for ingredient in ingredients:
                ingredient_label = Label(text=ingredient, font_size=16)
                card.ids.ingredients_grid.add_widget(ingredient_label)

            # Adding the instructions
            instructions = recipe['instructions']
            instruction_label = Label(text=instructions, font_size=16, halign='left', valign='top')
            card.ids.instructions_grid.add_widget(instruction_label)


class MyRecipesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('recipe_card.kv')
        return RecipesScreen()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyRecipesApp().run()
```

the kivy bit

```
<RecipeCard>:
    AsyncImage:
        source: root.image
        size_hint: 1, 0.6
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 0.4
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.4}
        padding: dp(10)

        Label:
            text: root.title
            font_size: '20sp'
            bold: True
            size_hint: 1, 0.2

        Label:
            text: root.description
            font_size: '16sp'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            GridLayout:
                id: ingredients_grid
                cols: 1
                spacing: dp(5)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Label:
                    text: 'Ingredients:'
                    font_size: '16sp'
                    bold: True
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: dp(30)

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
            GridLayout:
                id: instructions_grid
                cols: 1
                spacing: dp(5)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                Label:
                    text: 'Instructions:'
                    font_size: '16sp'
                    bold: True
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: dp(30)
                    valign: 'middle'

                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
```

The aim eventually is to have the window titled with the recipe name and having an upper scrollable window displaying the ingredients and a lower scrollable window displaying the method/instructions.

I have tried adjusting the position of the windows, their size, same for the text but it always ends up overlayed and pinned to the top of the screen. I can grab the text mash up and move it so I think the scrollview is working.

Comment: I have made slight progress on this, the scroll boxes are there, the image and text problems persist.

First though: It seems like Scrollview is displaying the text mashup outwith the frame boundaries.

I'm not sure how to post code blocks in these little comments but when I work it out I'll upload the latest mess I have created

Comment: Update. The scroll bars are there and appear to work. I believe.
When I work out how to mark this as solved I will